# Symfony2 Podio-Php podio api

Tags: php, api, symfony, podio

im supposed to use get item values but it is not in podio-php client, and i have little to no experience with api

i have looked around and found a work around
getting all the item id on app
then looping through all the id and all the fields in the app
problem is, its very slow, so am i doing something wrong?

here's some of my code

```
foreach ($item_collection['items'] as $item_key => $item) {

        $pname[] = (\PodioItem::get_field_value($item->item_id, 46702393));
        $channel[] = (\PodioItem::get_field_value($item->item_id, 46702394));
```

and i have like more than 30 ids and 17 or so fields

PS: im using symfony2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already gotten an item collection there's no need for any more API requests. When you call PodioItem::get_field_value() inside a loop like that it will be extremely slow because you are making a request to a remote server.

In this case it's unnecessary because you already have all the data. `$item` contains all the field values:

```
foreach ($item_collection['items'] as $item_key => $item) {
    $pname[] = $item->field(46702393);
    $channel[] = $item->field(46702394);
```

$pname and $channel now contains an array of PodioItemField objects that you can work on.